# How to disable ExtJs validation errors during reload?

Tags: extjs

I have a dependent combo box that is required.  When the parent combo box value is selected, the dependent combo is cleared and the store is reloaded.  How do I keep the ExtJs validation error from showing during the reload?

```
            new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                id: 'ddlMake',
                store: makeStore,
                displayField: 'Description',
                valueField: 'TypeCode',
                width: 110,
                typeAhead: true,
                mode: 'local',
                forceSelection: true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                emptyText: 'Select a make',
                selectOnFocus: true,
                allowBlank: false,
                listeners:
                    {
                        select: function (combo, record, index) {
                            var selVal = Ext.getCmp('ddlMake').getValue();
                            var modelCombo = Ext.getCmp('ddlModel');
                            modelCombo.setValue('');
                            modelCombo.store.reload({
                                params: { categoryTypeCode: 'MODEL', subCategoryTypeCode: selVal }
                            });
                        }
                    }
            }),
            new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                id: 'ddlModel',
                store: modelStore,
                displayField: 'Description',
                valueField: 'TypeCode',
                width: 110,
                typeAhead: true,
                mode: 'local',
                forceSelection: true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                emptyText: 'Select a model',
                selectOnFocus: true,
                allowBlank: false
            }),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Reset() method will clear any validation messages.  Here is what I ended up using:

```
function LoadModelCombo(combo, record, index) {
    var selVal = Ext.getCmp('ddlMake').getValue();

    if (selVal != '') {
        var modelCombo = Ext.getCmp('ddlModel');
        modelCombo.setValue('');
        modelCombo.store.reload({
            params: { categoryTypeCode: 'MODEL', subCategoryTypeCode: selVal }
        });
        modelCombo.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to reset, you can temporarily set allowblank to true before load, and when store loads set it back to false

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the exact code, but there are methods to silence other listeners - See docs for stopEvent and stopPropogation.